# When should "rnano" be used in place of "nano"?

Tags: security, nano

I like `nano` and use it a lot. A related application is `rnano`.

From the `rnano` manual:

```
DESCRIPTION
       rnano  runs  the  nano  editor in restricted mode.  This allows editing
       only the specified file or files, and doesn't allow the user access  to
       the filesystem nor to a command shell.

       In restricted mode, nano will:

       • not allow suspending;

       • not allow saving the current buffer under a different name;

       • not allow inserting another file or opening a new buffer;

       • not allow appending or prepending to any file;

       • not make backup files nor do spell checking.
```

When should I be using `rnano`?

Comment: Vim similarly has `vim -Z`/`rvim`, whose documentation states "the user may still find a loophole to execute a shell command, it has only been made difficult."

Comment: Not just editors - shells exist with a "restricted" mode, also mostly using the `r` prefix convention.  These should also be used only to guard against accident rather than against malice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suspect the intended use-case for `rnano` (or `nano -R`) is to provide an editor usable in privileged scenarios, or with untrusted keyboard input. For example, if you want to give someone else an editor using your account — they wouldn’t be able to access other files. Likewise, it would be useful to limit the danger of `sudo` access to an editor; but in such cases `sudoedit` should be used instead.

Restricted mode [was added in version 1.3.3](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/ChangeLog.1999-2006#n3594), released in June 2004. The [initial patch](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/nano-devel/2004-02/msg00005.html) from February 2004 doesn’t give much rationale:

> Recently I needed a small text editor that could be secured in such a way that it would only edit a specific file or files, and not allow the user access to the underlying filesystem or a command shell. I chose to use nano, since it was easy to use. However, I had to patch it a bit, since while it has a chroot-like mode, this wasn't sufficiently secure.

David Lawrence Ramsey [extended the patch quite a bit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/commit/?id=d893fa946db3558a7837e82c722da662a9071fc4) before merging it in April 2004.

Other editors have restricted modes, with varying definitions of “restricted”; for example, [Vim 5 added a restricted mode](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version5.txt#L615) in 2002 (invoked using `-Z` or `rvim`, same as the original `rnano` patch) which prevents any access to an external shell.

Comment: But how does `sudoedit` prevent the editor from accessing other files, like `rnano` does?

Comment: @Barmar since the editor run by `sudoedit` runs as the original user (not the privileged user), it can only access files the original user would be able to access anyway.

Comment: Oh right. It works on a copy of the file.

Comment: And working on a copy of the file would be much safer than trying to limit the exposure of letting the user access a privileged process as large as an editor, IMO. That is, in the context of sudo, where the unprivileged user usually has a general-use account. If, on the other hand, one wants to create a restricted user accessible over SSH, then something like rnano might come into it (though again it might be better to just provide some sort of an endpoint where the user can provide the complete file after editing it remotely.)

Comment: That link provides very little rationale beyond, "I sleep better at night." It doesn't even describe the use case. That patch author was clearly more invested in their use case than in nano, although I suppose the PR reviewers had a chance to catch anything dubious. It's much better to use standard techniques and tools (sudoedit, in this case) rather than a special mode that was developed to support one person.

Comment: @jpaugh, come now. It's not like nano is even the only editor to have a restricted mode.

Comment: @ilkkachu The name of the feature is one thing I haven't complained about. Although, I suppose I could, for good measure. ;-) Umm... The name makes it sound very official and well supported, despite its humble origin and underspecified use case.

Answer (score 3):

You might use it in `sudoers` like this, to allow a selected set of users to edit a particular configuration file

```
Cmnd_alias EDITFILE = rnano /path/to/that/file
User_alias FILEEDITORS = user1, user2
User_alias FILEOWNER = otheruser
FILEEDITORS ALL=(FILEOWNER) EDITFILE
```

The file should be only writable by `otheruser`, so these users can't edit it normally. Then they'll be able to use:

```
sudo -u otheruser rnano /path/to/that/file
```

They'll be able to edit the file, but not do anything else with that user's privileges, because `rnano` prohibits accessing other files or exiting to a shell.

Comment: That’s what `sudoedit` already does — a user can be granted edit access to `/path/to/that/file`, and they’ll be able to edit that file, using the editor of their choice, but nothing else requiring privilege. The editor started by `sudoedit` runs as the original user, not the privileged user, so it’s even safer than `rnano`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use it to let people edit selected file(s) without giving them shell access.**

Let's say Steve the Secretary needs to be able to assign employees to various company e-mail aliases. However, you don't feel like giving Steve a full-blown shell account on the company mail server, because that would allow him to poke around and execute arbitrary commands. Perhaps Steve gets bored one day and finds an exploitable command on the server which they can use to read the CEO's private conversations, or Steve's single-use account gets compromised by some malware and used to deploy a bitcoin miner on the server. All sorts of unpleasant things can happen when people have privileges they don't need.

So what do you do? You make an account for Steve on the mail server, but you configure it to only allow `rnano /etc/aliases` and nothing else. You can do it using the `ForceCommand` option in `sshd_config`, or using `command=` in `authorized_keys` (in which case they don't even need their own account), or by configuring their login shell accordingly if they will be logging in using something else than SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It could be used to provide an editor window as part of some other application.

An easy example would be fixing a merge conflict (I think CVS workflows worked a lot like this) or editing an error feedback message before sending it.

It doesn't even have to be privileged, just not desirable to change the file name.

Comment: But when you edit core, the files are usually under your own user account, so you can edit them with any editor in any case. So there's no reason to (try to) enforce a restricted editor for fixing merge conflicts or commit messages or whatever.

Comment: See the last line.  When you run 'git rebase -i' or similar there's no desirable reason for the user to be able to change the filename of the buffer they're editing and if they can't it makes your code to slurp it back in a heck of a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: Yes, of course they shouldn't save the file under another name. Usually they also don't do that, because, well, why would they? Also, usually the editor user interface makes it relatively simple to just save using the same name. But why would you need to disable inserting other files, or launching external programs (which is usually also prevented in restricted editors, though maybe `nano` doesn't support it to begin with). Why would you want to restrict what the user can do, when there's no real technical reason to do that? Sorry, I'm not buying that.

Comment: Fixing weird `tmp.OIyX5pUHgA` to `filename.txt` is exactly what non-techie users would likely do even though it breaks your script that totally expected you to edit the temporary file. So it can make sense to launch a restricted editor to prevent just that. Usability works in such strange ways sometimes. But perhaps we're all looking for purpose where there isn't any. Searching on Github and other places I don't find rvim / rnano used much anywhere at all.